# use sunmi inner printer in ionic

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3, ionic4

i'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer/

to print with the sunmi device from my ionic app

i declare var sunmiInnerPrinter:any;  before @ionicpage() and then i call sunmiInnerPrinter.methods()

anyway, when calling it, it fails, and i get ' sunmiInnerPrinter is not defined' error

i opened an issue here : https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer/issues/1

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone again the [SUNMI plugin](https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer)

```sh
mkdir ~/work
cd ~/work
git clone https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer
```

2. On **root folder** of your project

*Delete* plugins/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer

```sh
rm -rf plugins/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer
```

*Remove* cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer entry in your package.json

```
{
   "cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer": "/path/to/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer"
}
```

3. *Update* your project .

```sh
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform add browser@^6.0.0
```

4. *Insert* the [SUNMI plugin](https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer)

```sh
ionic cordova plugin add /PATH/TO/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer
```

5. *Update* packages

```sh
npm i
```

6. *See Detailed* information at [Github Issue #1](https://github.com/tmalbonph/cordova-plugin-sunmi-inner-printer/issues/1)